# file exists but in toast it's empty

Tags: java, android

The toast says the file exists, but after that the read response is empty. What can be the mistake?

Thanks

```
fileName = "locations.txt";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/doma/" + fileName);

    String response = "";

    if (file.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BufferedReader br;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "cp1252"));
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line + '\n') ;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "read:\n" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, " + fileName + " doesn't exist!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: IF your referring to response it was empty `Toast.makeText(this, "read:\n" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: yeah, the variable response is empty, but it should not be. What can be the problem?

Comment: this should work...the file isn't empty, is it?

Comment: do you have an exeption raised in your try catch block?

Comment: Okay, the problem has been solved. Permission request was missing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your referring to response it was set empty `Toast.makeText(this, "read:\n" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Your toast must be file and not fileName .. Where do you get the value of fileName?

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/doma/" + fileName);

    String response = "";

    if (file.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BufferedReader br;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "cp1252"));
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; response += line + '\n') ;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Toast.makeText(this, "read:\n" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                .show();
    } else {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, " + file + " doesn't exist!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }
```

Comment: You are right, I fixed it, still nothing in the toast

Comment: Now, Double check this `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/doma/" + fileName);`

Comment: Okay, the problem has been solved. Permission request was missing. Thanks for the help!